# Emulating `docker run` using the golang docker API

Tags: go, docker

How can I achieve the equivalent of

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name my-python-container -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:2-slim python test.py
```

using the Docker API for Golang?

Either https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient or https://github.com/samalba/dockerclient is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient`, you have to first [create a container](http://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#Client.CreateContainer), using the [`CreateContainerOptions`](http://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#CreateContainerOptions) to add the same options that you can via the command line.

```
container, err := client.CreateContainer(createContainerOptions)
```

Once you have the container, you [start it](http://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#Client.StartContainer), with any extra options or overrides in the [`HostConfig`](http://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#HostConfig)

```
client.StartContainer(container.ID, hostConfig)
```

To connect to the std io streams of a container, you need to use [`client.AttachToContainer`](http://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#Client.AttachToContainer), and assign the appropriate stream in the `AttachToContinerOptions`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you by any chance have a pointer to an example of writing to stdin and capturing stdout from such a container?

Comment: @AlexFlint: Added a line about attaching to the running container. You may need to set the Stdin, Stdout, or Stderr bool flags on that call to get it to work, or the Attach* options when you create the container. I don't have a test setup at the moment to confirm what way is best, or if they differ.

Comment: The missing piece of the answer here is how to add those bind mounts asked about in the OP (`-v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp`) . https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient/issues/633 gets started on this, but doesn't end up with a satisfying answer.