# Golang Docker API - Tail container logs

Tags: docker, go

I'm using Go and hitting Docker's API to pull an image, and then create and execute a container. Specifically I'm using the [docker-newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman-docker) image. I can see that it's actually being executed in Kitematic, so I know that everything is setup correctly. However, my Go application isn't attaching and then tailing the logs being output.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30653273/1478636), and it references what appears to be the way to attach to the image and view the log. I can't seem to get it to work regardless of what I try.

```
attachToContainerOptions := docker.AttachToContainerOptions{
    Container: container.ID,
    OutputStream: os.Stdout,
    ErrorStream:  os.Stderr,
    Logs: true,
    Stdout: true,
    Stderr: true,
}
if err := client.AttachToContainer(attachToContainerOptions); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

No error occurs, but this immediatley gets passed over without streaming anything to the console. How do I get this to stream to the console until the docker cmd completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Attach only works on a running container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) and the container lifetime for that image is ephemeral. Try [*Client.Logs](https://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#Client.Logs), instead, to get the resulting logs.

Here is a code sample:

```
logsOptions := docker.LogsOptions{
    Container:    container.ID,
    OutputStream: os.Stdout,
    ErrorStream:  os.Stderr,
    Follow:       true,
    Stdout:       true,
    Stderr:       true,
}
if err := client.Logs(logsOptions); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: That was the correct solution, I added a code sample I got working since I haven't seen one online as a working example.